# Explicitly declare the column name for a navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm trying to use Entity Framework 6.1.3 with an Oracle 12c database server. I have been warned. But I'm not yet ready to tell the customer that it's impossible. I have already put a number of hacks in place. Now I need another one. Generated column names can easily be longer than 30 characters but Oracle is still unable to handle those. So I thought I just use the `ColumnAttribute` for those properties but it's simply ignored for navigation properties.

Here's some sample code:

```
public class Component
{
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    [Column("ParentIF")]
    public virtual Interface ParentInterface { get; set; }
}
public class Interface
{
    public int InterfaceId { get; set; }
}
```

The generated name would be "ParentInterface_InterfaceId". I want to change it to a shorter "ParentIF". The above code does not work, it still uses the longer name.

Some code I've found elsewhere uses something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Fix reference column names to support Oracle's 30 characters restriction.
    // Entity Framework ignores Column attribute on reference columns.
    modelBuilder.Entity<Component>()
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentIF"));

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

But this is incomplete. It's lacking the specification which column should be mapped like this. I can't find the missing pieces. And it doesn't compile.

Another idea was using something like the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Component>()
    .Property(c => c.ParentInterface)
    .HasColumnName("ParentIF");
```

This gives me a compiler error CS0453 which I don't understand.

Is there any way to explicitly define what column name must be used for a reference property in Entity Framework Code First?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to add another property to your model for the interface Id:

```
public int ParentInterfaceId { get; set; }
```

Now you can control the column name with the `Column` attribute:

```
[Column("ParentIF")]
public int ParentInterfaceId { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's not a reference property. I'd really like to keep those to take advantage of EF. If I need to fetch all associated records myself, I might as well use easier O/R mappers that work seamlessly with Oracle. (I happen to have written one myself.)

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you are saying. This solution is only making the name of the column explicit, nothing else. It doesn't change your model in any way.

Comment: What name must I use for the additional property? How does EF detect that the two properties are related?

Comment: You can either let EF make the association itself (it will take virtual `PropertyX` and link it to `PropertyXId`) or manually specify it with the `ForeignKey` attribute.

Comment: That works. Now I still have collection properties left which get the long column name in the opposite (referencing) table.

Comment: You can do the same thing, in the child model (i.e. the one that is in the collection) add a property that refers to the parent object ID.